# when generating a number, only gives 0

Tags: android

when i generate a problem or number in this case, it seems to always come out as 0, when it should be generating a number between 0 and the value AD given. which in this case is 0 through 11, but only generates a 0 every time. for some reason the AD int is returning as 1 when i log it to the debug console. any help?

```
Double d = Math.random() * Max1;
    O1 = d.intValue();
    Log.d("BasicsPractice.java","the GenerateOperation function generated : " + O1 + " : as the number to determin the operation to be built");
    if(O1 == 0) {
        if(AddP == true) {
            int AD = DM.AddDiff + 1;
            Double d1 = Math.random() * AD;
            A1 = d1.intValue();
            Log.d("BasicsPractice.java","the first Addition number generated was: " + A1);
            Double d5 = Math.random() * AD;
            A2 = d5.intValue();
            Log.d("BasicsPractice.java","the second Addition number generated was: " + A2);
            Output = A1 + " + " + A2;
            Log.d("BasicsPractice.java","the outputted problem was: " + Output);
            OutputToProblemView();
        }
```

Comment: `AD` is obviously 0 if you get 0.

Comment: AD cannot be 0 because it is set to 10 by default by DM.AddDiff and then 1 is added on to it

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the input values ? Max 1 , DM.AddDiff , variable types of A1,A2
I tried the if block in AddP==true , I get values between 0 and 11

Comment: `  int AD = 10 + 1;
        Double d1 = Math.random() * AD;
       int A1 = d1.intValue();
        Log.d("BasicsPractice.java","the first Addition number generated was: " + A1);
        Double d5 = Math.random() * AD;
       int A2 = d5.intValue();
        Log.d("BasicsPractice.java","the second Addition number generated was: " + A2);
        String Output = A1 + " + " + A2;
        Log.d("BasicsPractice.java","the outputted problem was: " + Output);  `

Comment: Max1 is only going to at max 0 through 3. DM.AddDiff is practically the same as AD. A1 and A2 are integers

Comment: @connormurry, you can argue all you want, `AD` is 0.

Answer (score -1):

`Math.random()` returns a number from 0.0 to 1.0. So you need to convert it into `int`.

Try this out.

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*12);
```

This will generate numbers between 0 to 11.

Comment: Math.floor is redundant since casting to int implies that.